# How to add control to switch between styles of one layer leaflet

Tags: leaflet

i have a one layer with 3 styles SLD (symbologys) published in geoserver, with leaflet map i can switch betwwen many layers with L.control(.....).addTomap
now i need to switch between styles of one layer use leaflet?

Comment: It's gonna be easier to have three different instances of `L.TileLayer.WMS`, each of those with its `style`, and add them to a `L.Control.Layers`.

Comment: i don't have three different instances it's just one with three styles!!